# "ActionView::Template::Error: marshal data too short" in Ruby on Rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, marshalling, sprockets, actionview

I'm doing Ruby on Rails app development in the Cloud9 IDE.  I ran into a vexing problem when doing "bundle exec rake test", with the following error message for all tests performed (error messages were more verbose, but all contained this nugget):

"ActionView::Template::Error: marshal data too short"

I searched extensively here and elsewhere for forum Q&A on this topic.  Most had to do with database issues.  The app that I'm developing hasn't gotten to the database part yet, so none of these were of help.  The few other postings also did not relate to my situation.

I'm sharing my solution here in case anyone else might benefit.

It was necessary to delete all of the temporary Sprockets files within the following directories (replace "my_app" with your app's directory name):

./my_app/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets

./my_app/tmp/cache/assets/test/sprockets

After this the error messages went away.  These spurious errors were at risk of keeping my future tests from being accurate.

I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow.  Please forgive me if offering a question with an answer already provided is somehow against the spirit of the site.

Comment: The usual way to do that is to provide your answer as an actual answer (ie not in the body of the question). As it is, your question will show up as "unanswered" in searches